# Managing database Users when restoring backups across environments

Tags: sql-server, users, automation

I have numerous Azure SQL Server Databases that teammates backup and restore. The issue we're running into is regarding the Users on these databases.  We have Azure AD Groups that contain the respective users that can access the databases. We have a group for read, write, etc. The groups are defined on an environment level. We have some groups that have access to the UAT databases, others only Production. When a privileged user does a backup and restore of Production -> UAT, we need to remove the Production group and add the UAT group.

We'd love to be able to automate this so that there is no possibility it is overlooked.

Are there any ingenious ways to monitor and manage the Users when doing a restore?